# How to align two widgets in a QHBoxLayout where one is aligned far left, and one is aligned far right?

Tags: qt, alignment, qt5

I want to have a `QHBoxLayout` where one `QLabel` is on the far left, the one `QLabel` is on the far right.

My *Google-fu* fails me.  `:(`  I cannot find the solution.

Here is a screenshot of the `QHBoxLayout` with two `QLabel` widgets:

[image]

Whatever I try, I cannot get the second `QLabel` widget aligned on the far right.

Roughly speaking, I tried something like this:

```
QHBoxLayout* const hboxLayout = new QHBoxLayout{};
hboxLayout->addWidget(m_leftLabel, 1);
hboxLayout->addStretch(1);
hboxLayout->addWidget(m_rightLabel, 0, Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignRight);
```

I tried various large stretch values for the first `addWidget()` call and `addStretch()`.

I also tried:

```
m_rightLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignmentFlag::AlignRight)
```

None of these solutions works.  I am sure the solution is very simple ( ! ), but I cannot find it.

How can I do this?

Comment: I guess your layout is not set as the layout of your dialog. Then it isn’t active. Either create the layout with the parent widget or dialog as an argument in the constructor or call setLayout on the parent widget later on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is to set a stretch in the middle:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout *lay = new QHBoxLayout(&w);
    lay->addWidget(new QLabel("Left"));
    lay->addStretch();
    lay->addWidget(new QLabel("Right"));
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: This minimum reproducible example was very helpful!  I found the issue.  I am actually adding a widget to `QStatusBar` and this has some special rules around layouts.  Your example helped me to find that bug.  `:)`